# asp:Login "Remember me" is expiring sooner than the full 50 years

Tags: asp.net, cookies, authentication, remember-me

The ASP.net `<asp:Login>` control has an ability to display a **Remember me next time** checkbox. If checked, this [`Login.RememberMeSet Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.remembermeset.aspx) is set.

**From MSDN:**

> When the **RememberMeSet** property is **true**, the authentication cookie sent to the user's computer is set to expire in 50 years, making it a persistent cookie that will be used when the user next visits the Web site. Because the authentication cookie will be present on the user's computer, the user will be considered already authenticated and will not have to log in to the Web site again.

Except that it seems that the cookie is expiring after 30 minutes, rather than 50 years:

[image]

(unless this is a *session* cookie, rather than a *persistent* cookie. I don't know how to tell the difference)

How do I get `asp:Login` to **actually** "*remember me*" for 50 years?

> **Note**: I do know there's the bug in ASP.net that you have to give the cookie a suffix name, in `web.config`:
>
> ```
> <authentication mode="Forms">
>   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
> </authentication>
> ```
>
> Without a `name` being added, the `asp:Login` control will fail to <strike>work.</strike> remember the user at all; even for 30 minutes.

Comment: From what I remember the Remember Me functionality is left up to you to implement and does not work out of the box (see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621380/asplogin-control-remember-me-is-not-remembering-me)

Comment: That question does suggest that but the documentation doesn't suggest that at all!

Comment: "unless that is a session cookie, rather than a persistent cookie" - a session cookie doesn't usually get written to disk at all and is just stored in memory. (this assumes you mean a session lifetime cookie rather than the cookie that identifies the session on the server).

Comment: I remember having problems when using `http://localhost` - Have you had this error on a server or just locally? If just locally, try the FQDN to your machine and not "localhost"